# Dúvida no html.Dropdownlist alimentado por uma ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: preciso enviar, ao invés de o `Id` da `ViewBag`, o `Municipio`, que está contido na `ViewBag.Cidades`.

Como Faço para mudar do Id para o `Municipio` quando clico em Buscar para enviar o Municipio através do controlador?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Colecao", "Cliente", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cidades)
    </td>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Município é um atributo de Cidades?

Comment: pode por mais detalhes, copia da classe "Cidades" ?